# SQL Query Get the Next ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am working on a problem where I need to get the next available Category for a gamer. If the gamer has reached the final Category (Shooter in below image) then I will need to go back to the start of the table and go to the next one available.

Below is a list of Category:

[image]

Below is a list of gamers and what their last Category_ID was:

[image]

Finally, below is the data I will be using to work with

[image]

Now I need to find the next Category_ID for each gamer using the data table. If a Gamer has reached the last Category_ID (ID 4 in this case and Gamer C) then it will reset back to top like 1 however Gamer C will pick Category 2 as there is no one for that Gamer.

How can I pick the next Category available using the data table for each gamer while keeping in mind of resetting back to top if reached end?

Below is a code example of the problem:

```
DECLARE @Category AS TABLE
(
    Category_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) ,
    Description VARCHAR(255)
)

INSERT INTO @Category
VALUES('Sports'), ('Adventure'), ('Action'), ('Shooter')

DECLARE @Gamer AS TABLE
(
    Username VARCHAR(255) ,
    Last_Category_ID INT
)

INSERT INTO @Gamer
VALUES('Gamer A', 1), ('Gamer B', 2), ('Gamer C', 4), ('Gamer D', 3)

DECLARE @Data AS TABLE
(
    Username VARCHAR(255) ,
    Play_At DATETIME ,
    Category_ID INT
)
INSERT INTO @Data
VALUES('Gamer A', GETDATE() -1, 1), ('Gamer B', GETDATE() -1, 2), ('Gamer A', GETDATE() -1, 3), ('Gamer D', GETDATE() -1, 3), ('Gamer C', GETDATE() -1, 2)


SELECT * FROM @Category
SELECT * FROM @Gamer
SELECT * FROM @Data
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the next unused category id for each gamer.  And then to start over when all are done.

Here is an approach:

- For each gamer, get the maximum current category.
- For each category, get the next category.
- Get the first category as well.
- When there is no next category use the first.

This is a good opportunity to use lateral joins:

```
select g.*, coalesce(cn.category_id, cf.category_id)
from @gamers g outer apply
     (select max(category_id) as max_category_id
      from @data d
      where d.username = g.username
     ) c outer apply
     (select top (1) cn.category_id
      from @categories cn
      where cn.categoryid > c.max_categoryid
     ) cn cross join
     (select min(cf.category_id) as categoryi_d
      from @categories cf
     ) cf;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ebd68f3c9a47a9f93046d0b6a6b31ea9) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear on if your `@Data` table represents the starting category however this might be what you need, if not by all means please clarify with some clear expected results for the sample data.

Using an `apply` to determine the starting category for each user (if indeed that's what your description entails) and another to get the maximum possible category, select the username and, using a `case expression`, the corresponding next category name or the starting category if it's already the max category.

```
select 
    Username, 
    (   select description 
        from @category c
        where c.category_Id=case when Last_Category_ID<m.Id then Last_Category_ID + 1 else startcat.Id end
    ) NextCategory
from @gamer g
outer apply (
    select min(category_id) Id
    from @data d
    where d.username=g.Username
)startcat
outer apply (
    select Max(category_Id) Id
    from @category
)m
```